# MySQL slow inserts

Tags: mysql, performance, prepared-statement

I have a MySql 8 database server running locally on a decent spec gaming laptop.
When I try to insert a number of records (500k) stored in an in-memory structure in Java via the following code it is extremely slow, we are talking about maybe 1000 records per minute at most.

I don't really know where to look for debug information or what metrics I should provide here to help answer this post, so if you have any guidance or additional information I can supply then please do let me know.

I've temporarily worked around this by saving the data to an in-memory H2 database but really I'd like to persist it and query it at leisure using the MySql workbench.

```
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(insertSQL);


        ArrayList<String> stocks = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Spread spread : spreads) {


            ps.setInt(1, spread.buyFeedId);
            ps.setInt(2, spread.sellFeedId);
            ps.setString(3, spread.stock);
            ps.setString(4, spread.buyExchange);
            ps.setString(5, spread.sellExchange);
            ps.setTimestamp(6, new Timestamp(spread.spreadDateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli())); 
            ps.setDouble(7, spread.buyPrice);
            ps.setDouble(8, spread.sellPrice);
            ps.setDouble(9, spread.diff);
            ps.setInt(10, spread.askSize);
            ps.setInt(11, spread.bidSize);

            ps.execute();
```

Comment: Is the table over-indexed? Does inserting the same data via the command line (or other app) seem as slow?

Comment: Are you relying on autocommit, or are you starting a transaction? If you use autocommit, it will start and commit a transaction for every row, which is a lot of overhead. I recommend to commit every 1000 rows. You might also like: [Load Data Fast!](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/load-data-fast)

Comment: No index on the table.

Comment: I'll try without autocommit - thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP we have PDO library allowing to actually bulk the inserts in one transaction by using:

```
$sql = 'my sql statement';
$Conn = DAO::getConnection();
$stmt = $Conn->prepare($sql);
$Conn->beginTransaction();
foreach($data as $row)
{
    // now loop through each inner array to match bound values
    foreach($row as $column => $value)
    {
        $stmt->bindValue(':' . $column, $value, PDOUtils::getPDOParam($value));
    }                
    $stmt->execute();
}
$Conn->commit();
```

In your case with 1000+ inserts, only one transaction would be needed. I'me not java but for sure there is equivalent.

Comment: For what it's worth, you don't need to put the `':'` in your bind call. That was true in an old version of PDO, but not anymore. You can use the parameter name without the `:` prefix.

Comment: No worries. I just flinch every time I see the `.` concatenation operation in any database-related PHP code. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have all the 500K records handy and if you just want to insert, don't do insert operation line by line, but use BCP (Bulk copy program) functionality.

Read about mysqlimport or LOAD IN FILE commands and try implementing.

Answer (score 0):

Batch insert the rows.  That is, build a single `INSERT` for each 100-1000 rows.  This will run about 10 times as fast.  Using a "transaction" is a less effective way of batching.

Here's one discussion of Java + Batch:  https://www.viralpatel.net/batch-insert-in-java-jdbc/

Search this for other possible answers on this site:

```
site:stackoverflow.com  java  MySQL  batch  INSERT
```

Another speedup is to change to

```
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
```

That is a speed vs reliability tradeoff -- in favor of speed.

Comment: Thanks - I have explored batch insert before and yes the performance is much better, but I'm concerned that there is something slowing the processing down with general database usage as I'm sure the performance for very simple inserts like this should be orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: @DominicKeeley - A one-row insert is not helped (and not hurt) by using a "batch insert".